# Textfree Login Authentication Failing

Tags: c#, json, http, authentication, ssl

I am trying to create a C# application that logs in to a Pinger Textfree account and can send SMS messages from it. The web version of this service is flash-based so I have been using Fiddler and Wireshark to monitor the HTTP requests that it uses. I have written some code that I think should log in but I get a "Bad Credentials" response from the server, however, I do know that the username and password I am using are accurate. I am also pretty sure that they do not append anything extra to either as I would have seen this in Fiddler.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Connect as client to port 443
        string server = "api.pinger.com";
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, 443);

        // Create a secure stream
        using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false,
            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate), null))
        {
            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(server);
            byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("POST https://api.pinger.com/1.0/web/login HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                                                                "Host: api.pinger.com\r\n" +
                                                                "Connection: keep-alive\r\n" +
                                                                "Origin: http://pinger.com\r\n" +
                                                                "X-Rest-Method: POST\r\n" +
                                                                "Authorization: OAuth realm=\"https://api.pinger.com\", oauth_consumer_key=\"textfree-in-flash-web-free\", oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_signature=\"HNN8gdLdskKnrtK2jbyN68b9JWQ%3D\", oauth_timestamp=\"1406102776\", oauth_nonce=\"635733471764340000\"\r\n" +
                                                                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                                                                "Accept: */*\r\n" +
                                                                "Referer: http://pinger.com/tfw/textFree_web.swf\r\n" +
                                                                "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\n" +
                                                                "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n\r\n" +

                                                                //json info                                                                    
                                                                "{\"password\":\"testing\",\"username\":\"myquestion\",\"clientId\":\"textfree-in-flash-web-free-1406143265-10D066F9-8126-CD00-4C3D-64AB7BA4FF52\"}\r\n"
                                                              );

            sslStream.Write(data);
            data = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            do
            {
                bytesRead = sslStream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data, 0, bytesRead))
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(ms))
                {
                    string returnData = rd.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.WriteLine(returnData);
                }
            } while (bytesRead != 0);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
```

PS I created the account with these credentials (User: myquestion, Pass: testing) just for this question so they are correct and it should be working.

I am using the headers and formatting that the requests I recorded with Fiddler used.

My guesses as to why this attempt has failed is that I am either not posting the json correctly or the authorization header is incorrect or its the "clientId" key in the json. I have done a lot of trial and error as well as research and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Pinger might be doing something clever like making sure a browser submits the request. What User Agent are you using? Also, you really should take some time to format the code in you question.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution on this?  I just started down this same route and am experiencing the same problem. :(

Comment: @SQLismylife So I wound up abandoning Pinger's TextFree and used TextNow. I wrote an API around it in C#. If you would like me to upload it somewhere let me know